# Trying to run python environments in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, environment

I've downloaded Anaconda Navigator for windows, and during the install process there was a recommendation to install VSCode. I went along with it, and it seems to have a lot of the features I was looking for in a python IDE. But I'm stuck on how to run it with different environments.

I have tried selecting an environment in the Anaconda `Environments` tab, and then clicking `Home` and launching VSCode. It seems to work to some extent. In the terminal, `where.exe python` gets me

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PYTHON_ENV\python.exe
```

but when I try to check the modules that are available in that environment, it fails. I know they modules are available because I can see them in the Anaconda Navigator `Environments` tab, or if I start a terminal directly from the `Environments` tab. This is how it fails at the terminal within VSCode:

```
PS H:\> python -m import sys
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PYTHON_ENV\python.exe: No module named import
H:\> python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    help()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> quit()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    quit()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just in case this is an XY problem, what I'm actually trying to do is run some code I cloned from github which has a PyQt4 dependency. When I open the file in VSCode and try to run it, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named PyQt4`. I can get it to run from a terminal, but I'd like to know how to do it with VSCode too.

Comment: Looks like there's something else going on with your install.  I'd uninstall all Pythons and do a fresh reinstall of Anaconda with Python 3.6 btw.

Comment: This is an almost fresh install. I downloaded it yesterday. The python repository I will be working with most of the time is still on python2.7, so that's why I went with Anaconda2. If there are no other ideas, I will try Anaconda3 and within that I will use a python2.7 environment.

Comment: I use python2.7 in anaconda3.

Comment: uninstall-reinstall didn't go so well. I ran into this problem: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/IFICnPq1-So/AuswVSQyAwAJ